# tensorflow constrain the optimized tensor

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization

I want to constrain the updates by clipping the updated variables. I know the boundary of variables so i need to constrain it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rosen(x):
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)

x0 = np.array([1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2])

"Trial #1"
x    = tf.Variable(x0)
opt  = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
ls   = []
clip_min = [0,0,0,0,0]
clip_max = [2,2,2,2,2]
for _ in range(3000):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      tape.watch(x)
      loss = rosen(x)   
    ls.append(loss.numpy())    
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, x)   
    opt.apply_gradients(zip([grads], [x]))
    "This is the error !!!!!"
    x     = tf.clip_by_value(x, clip_value_min=clip_min, 
                              clip_value_max=clip_max)
sol1 = x.numpy()  
plt.plot(np.arange(len(ls)), ls)
```

It gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'
```

How to solve this??

Comment: Can you post the full traceback (error message)?

Comment: Hi, This is the full error message. It appears when i try to clip the variables at each iteration. In pytorch, I solve this by applying a torch.zero_grad(). But I don't how to do this in tensorflow

Comment: This is not the full traceback. Can you post the message that you get starting with `Traceback (most recent call last)` and ending with `AttributeError 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'`?. (Even if it is a lot of lines).